# CSS positioning styles impact on the other objects

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-position

I am working a project on my favorite science stories animated using HTML. While I was working on it By just changing the `position` to `fixed` or nothing position of all my objects was changing. If you remove the `position` property from `#Guy`, you will notice that the image of Galileo will shift drastically. I just want to know why this happens.

```css
:root {
  --initX: 280px;
  --initY: 70px;
  --finalY: 600px;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#Guy {
  z-index: 4;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  transform: translate(800px, 450px);
}

#Galilo {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(290px, 5px) rotateZ(4deg);
}

#tower {
  height: 650px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translate(250px, 50px) rotateZ(4deg);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
}

#Lball {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(var( --initX), var(--initY));
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  animation: lite 2s linear 1s infinite forwards;
}

#Hball {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translate(calc(var( --initX) + 75px), var(--initY));
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation: heavy 2s linear 1s infinite forwards;
}

#floor {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(0px, 565px);
}

#hide {
  height: 12%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(0px, 650px);
}

@keyframes lite {
  0% {
    transform: translate(var( --initX), var(--initY))
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(var(--initX), calc(var(--finalY) + 12.5px))
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(var(--initX), calc(var(--finalY) + 12.5px))
  }
}

@keyframes heavy {
  0% {
    transform: translate(calc(var( --initX) + 75px), var(--initY))
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(calc(var( --initX) + 75px), var(--finalY))
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(calc(var( --initX) + 75px), var(--finalY))
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tower"></div>
<div id="Hball"></div>
<div id="Lball"></div>
<div id="floor"></div>
<div id="hide"></div>
<img src="stick fidure.png" alt="Dude thinking" id="Guy">
<img src="galileo-galilei.png" alt="gallilo" id="Galilo">
```

P.S.

The link for the image of Galileo is https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/109/590x/galileo-galilei-819977.jpg and the stick figure was made in Paint 3D

Comment: Please add a small demo

Comment: If you read through the differences between `static` (The default position, which what is being applied when you don't set it yourself) and `fixed` in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), it should help you understand why the layout changes.

Comment: It is still not clear exactly what is being asked. By default all elements affect each other. Changing layout for one element (such as setting it to use absolute or fixed positioning) will therefore affect other elements. If you truly still wonder about this then make a minimal test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed` takes the element out of the document flow and places it in relation to the viewport/window. Usually that also causes this element to overlap other elements. The other elements however will be rearranged in a way like the fixed element wouldn't be there (it's not in the document flow). So adding/removing `position: fixed` to/from an element will have all these effects on the overall document.